# How can I run single groovy class file independently in gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradlew

I have 2 groovy class files under one rootProject. I want to run just one of them without running the other one. How can I do that using intellij command line and command prompt. Right now when I run the rootProject both files run one after the other. Is there any setting required build.gradle file then please explain hoow can I do that as I am very new to gradle and don't know much about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have only those two groovy scripts (and there is nothing to compile etc.), you do not need Gradle to run it at all. From command line call

```
groovy <filename>.groovy
```

To run the script directly from Gradle Script, use

```
new GroovyShell().run(file('somePath'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create intellij config to run your script.

Follow these steps:

1) Edit configuration

[image]

2) Add new Groovy configuration

[image]

3) Browse you script
[image]

4) Run your script
[image]